# Spring RestFul x nginx как правильно обрабатывать запросы

Tags: java, spring, nginx, rest, vds

Имею обычный **Spring RestFul** сервис, чисто тестовый, а так же домен http://ewrey.site, решил соединить через **nginx**, отправляя запрос на сервер по ip http://85.193.88.216:8080/user получаю ответ что сервер работает, так же если http://ewrey.site:8080/user, но, в случае отправки http://ewrey.site/user получаю ответ от nginx "Page not found", хотя сам сервер прекрасно работает. Как можно объединить **RestFul** с **nginx** чтобы отображение было корректным?

*код ewrey.site.bak для nginx :*

```
server{
        server_name ewrey.site:

        listen 80:

        location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host:
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr:
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwaded_for:
        proxy_set_header X-Forwaded-Proto $scheme:

        client_max_body_size 0:
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000: includeSubDomains: preload":
        add_header Referrer-Policy "same-origin":

        proxy_pass http://10.8.0.13:8080:
        }
}
```

код контроллера rest:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import web.MySite.entity.UserEntity;
import web.MySite.exceptions.UserAlreadyExistsException;
import web.MySite.exceptions.UserNotFoundException;
import web.MySite.service.UserService;

@RestController             // Создание REST контроллера
@RequestMapping("/user")    // Создание "начала" запроса, если начало /users то идет обработка
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService; // Иньенкция репозитория c логикой обработки входящих данных
    
    @PostMapping // POST Запрос 
    public ResponseEntity registartion(@RequestBody UserEntity user) { // У запроса должно быть тело в виде JSON {"name":"any","password":"any_pass"}
        try {
             userService.registration(user);
             return ResponseEntity.ok("Пользователь "+user.getName()+" - сохранен, данные прочитаны");
         }
        catch (UserAlreadyExistsException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
         catch(Exception e){
             return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Произошла ошибка : ");
         }
    }
    
    @GetMapping // GET запрос 
    public ResponseEntity getUser() {
         try {
             return ResponseEntity.ok("Сервер работает!");
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Произошла ошибка");
         }
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/") // GET запрос с параметрами
    public ResponseEntity getUserOne(@RequestParam Long id) { // GET запрос c параметрами http:/localhost:8080/user/?id=1
         try {
             return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUserOne(id));
         }
         catch(UserNotFoundException e) {
             return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Пользователь не найден");
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто пробросить на сервере 80 порт, на 8080.

Comment: Не сработает :((

Answer (score 0):

Спустя несколько часов поиска информации я понял, что сам вопрос был составлен некорректно.

Для начала в **ngnix** есть четкое распределение между тем что отображается и тем что уходит в запрос, фактически, мы можем играться с конфигурациями ngnix.conf и выстраивать там логику переадресации и т.д, но, проще всего backend и frontend разделить (это не лучшее, но простое решение).

Что нужно для отображения и что отображается при переходе на сайт http://ewrey.site ?

А отображается файл из директории

**root /var/www/html;**

(Ubuntu)

Самое простое *(что сделал и я)* меняете в этой директории файл **index.nginx-debian.html** Не меняя названия, и получаете необходимый результат в виде вашего html файла
И уже в этом файле ставить запросы на кнопки и т.д и т.п креатив уместен

Есть также и сложный путь - заходим в файл **root /etc/nginx/nginx.conf** и там уже самостоятельно прописываем логику переадресации и т.д
([официальная документация от nginx на русском](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/))